# Does DB2 database have feature to add Sensitive Data Indicator to an Object?

Tags: db2

SQL Server gives a feature to add Sensitive Indicator for Columns/Objects to identify what kind of data is store in that Column.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (SNAME VARCHAR(1000))

ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO
dbo.STUDENT.SNAME
WITH ( LABEL='Highly Confidential', INFORMATION_TYPE='Financial', RANK=CRITICAL )
```

Then we can fetch this Information with the following query.

```
SELECT *FROM sys.sensitivity_classifications
```

Does DB2 have any feature similar to this?

SQLServer Documentation : [SQLServer_Documention_For_Sensitive_Data_Indicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-sensitivity-classification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

Db2 has the [security feature of Label-Based Access Control (LBAC)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=security-label-based-access-control-lbac). You can define and later assign security labels and policies to data. Moreover, you then define access control rules based on those labels.

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('Henrik', SECLABEL_BY_NAME('Highly Confidential', 'Financial') )
```